# laravel helper function base_path to be used inside class constant variable

Tags: php, laravel

What would be the best way of initializing a constant inside a class but it needs to load when calling laravel's base_path() helper function initially I have this code that throws an error because class constant has already ran

```
Class TestClass(){
  public const TEST_CONSTANT = base_path('path/to/file');
}
```

How should I refactor this code I tried adding a class variable and pre-define it inside and it works

```
Class TestClass(){
  private $testConstant;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->testConstant = base_path('path/to/file');
  }
}
```

my question is there any other way of refactoring this?

Comment: So you want a Contant with a dynamic value.... Doesn't that sound strange? Apart from that, this question is opinion based.

Comment: yes sort off because I need to use laravel base_path()

Comment: Sat the class constant to `path/to/file` and use the `base_path()`wherever you use it... But as said, thats an opinion

Comment: so TEST_CONSTANT = 'path_to_file' then in the constructor $this->testConstant=base_path(TEST_CONSTANT)?

Comment: No where you use the constant, `base_path(TestClass::TEST_CONSTANT)`

Comment: I really think you need to understand the difference between a constant and a variable. As the name shows: A constant has a fixed value, so never changes. So naming a variable or function `testConstant` is not done. You can put the path in a constant, but you cannot change the value on the go.